# Windows store app layout: ListView to fill remaining space

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, stackpanel

I would like to have Controls one above the other. One of them should be at the bottom, and there should be a ListView above it, which should fill all the available space left. I tried adding them to a StackPanel, with VerticalAlignment="Bottom", but then ListView is not scrollable, and doesn't care about the space it has left.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StackPanel will format to fit its contents, giving the ListView infinite space and then tacking the other control after, likely outside of the visible bounds. Instead use a Grid and set the Row heights to match your design. Something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0"></ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Height="auto" means to calculate the height based on the contents. Height="*" means to use the remaining space (or if there are multiple *s then divide the remaining space up). See the remarks in the [RowDefinition.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.rowdefinition.height.aspx) docs for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I wonder why the Tutorials never mentioned the auto setting.